# Numeric literals in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

What is the type that sql server assigns to the numeric literal: 2. , i.e. 2 followed by a dot?

I was curious because:

```
select convert(varchar(50), 2.)
union all
select convert(varchar(50), 2.0)
```

returns:

```
2
2.0
```

which made me ask what's the difference between 2. and 2.0 type wise?

Sql server seems to assign types to numeric literals depending on the number itself by finding the minimal storage type that can hold the number. A value of 1222333 is stored as int while 1152921504606846975 is stored as big int.

thanks

Edit: I also want to add why this is so important. In sql server 2008 r2, select 2/5 returns 0 while select 2./5 returns 0.4, due to the way sql server treats these types. In oracle and Access select 2/5 (oracle: select 2/5 from dummy) returns 0.4. That's the way it should be. I wonder if they fixed this behaviour in sql server 2012. I would be surprised if they did.

Answer (score 0):

This script might answer my question. The type of 2. is numeric(1, 0).

```
create table dbo.test_type (field sql_variant)
go

delete from dbo.test_type
go

INSERT INTO dbo.test_type
VALUES (2.);

INSERT INTO dbo.test_type
VALUES (2.0);


SELECT field
     , sql_variant_property (field
                           , 'BaseType')
         AS BaseType
     , sql_variant_property (field
                           , 'Precision')
         AS Precision
     , sql_variant_property (field
                           , 'Scale')
         AS Scale
  FROM dbo.test_type
```

It returns:

```
2     numeric   1   0
2.0   numeric   2   1
```

This is why when 2.0 is converted to varchar the result is 2.0. Sql server seems to record the precision.